# how to fetch data from flask app in react app on local server

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, cors, flask-cors

I have a flask app running on `localhost:5000`:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)   

@app.route("/api")
def parse():
    return {"test": "json"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # for production change debug to False
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And on the front end I'm fetching the data here:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("http://localhost:5000/api")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data: Data) => {
        setData(data);
        console.log(data);
      });
  }, []);
```

When I try and fetch the data from my react-app I get this error in the console:

[image]

I've seen a bunch of answers to similar questions, but all the other questions were more complicated than mine and I don't know what to add to my flask app since mine is pretty bare bones.

Comment: You might want to consider a solution using [Flask-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckly it's pretty simple to solve it. All you need to do is to install flask-CORS with `pip install flask-cors` and then add an CORS header on your app, like this:

```
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)   
CORS(app)
@app.route("/api")
def parse():
    return {"test": "json"}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # for production change debug to False
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[For more information, visit flask-cors documentation](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 0):

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET"])
def get_example():
    """GET in server"""
    response = jsonify(message="Simple server is running")

    # Enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin
    response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    return response
```

or

[image]